# How to inscribe the following shape with CSS inside div?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/0pexe6pk/)
[image]

### HTML

```
<div id="DiamondCenter">
    <div id="triangle-topleft"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#DiamondCenter {
    position:fixed;
    top:2%;
    left:48%;
    background: #24201a;
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    z-index:20 !important;
}
#triangle-topleft {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 40px solid gray;
    border-right: 40px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: With the orange border or without it?

Comment: Color doesnt matter I want make it look like diamond

Comment: SVG would be te way to go here rather than divs. No need to make this more complex than it needs to be really.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Using SVG**:

While using SVG, you could make use of `path` and `polyline` elements to draw the required shape. As indicated by Paulie_D in comments, SVG is the better choice for such complex shapes instead of CSS (though this can be achieved with CSS also).

The approach is very simple and is as follows:

- One `path` element for the top polygon which is drawn by joining the points at coordinates `(0,50)`, `(50,0)`, `(100,50)` and `(50,70)`.
- Another `path` element for the bottom polygon which is drawn by joining the points at `(0,50)`, `(50,70)` and `(100,50)`.
- One `polyline` element for the orange border which is nothing but a line connecting `(0,50)`, `(50,70)` and `(100,50)`.

```css
svg {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
path#top {
  fill: gray;
}
path#bottom {
  fill: black;
}
polyline#border {
  stroke: orange;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path id="top" d="M0,50 L50,0 100,50 50,70z" />
  <path id="bottom" d="M0,50 L50,100 100,50 50,70z" />
  <polyline id="border" points="0,50 50,70 100,50" />  
</svg>
```

---

**Using CSS:**

You can achieve the shape provided in question by using 2 pseudo-elements which are both rotated and skewed. The dimension of each pseudo-element is calculated using Pythagoras theorem.

The shape produced using this method is responsive and can adapt to changes in dimension. Hover the shape within the snippet to see how it adapts.

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#DiamondCenter {
  position: fixed;
  top: 2%;
  left: 48%;
  background: #24201a;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: 20 !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#DiamondCenter:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  bottom: 0px;
  left: -1px; /* half the width of border-left */
  height: calc(100% / 1.414);
  width: calc(100% / 1.414);
  background: black;
  border-left: 2px solid orange;
  transform: rotate(40deg) skewX(-20deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
#DiamondCenter:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: -1px; /* half the width of border-top */
  right: 0px;
  height: calc(100% / 1.414);
  width: calc(100% / 1.414);
  background: black;
  border-top: 2px solid orange;
  transform: rotate(-40deg) skewY(-20deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
}

/* Just for demo */

#DiamondCenter{
  transition: all 1s;
}
#DiamondCenter:hover{
  top: 5%;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div id="DiamondCenter"></div>
```

In the below snippet, I have set different background colors for the pseudo-elements to illustrate how the shape is achieved.

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#DiamondCenter {
  position: fixed;
  top: 2%;
  left: 48%;
  background: #24201a;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: 20 !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#DiamondCenter:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  bottom: 0px;
  left: -1px;
  height: calc(100% / 1.414);
  width: calc(100% / 1.414);
  background: seagreen;
  border-left: 2px solid orange;
  transform: rotate(40deg) skewX(-20deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
#DiamondCenter:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: -1px;
  right: 0px;
  height: calc(100% / 1.414);
  width: calc(100% / 1.414);
  background: skyblue;
  border-top: 2px solid orange;
  transform: rotate(-40deg) skewY(-20deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
}

/* Just for demo */

#DiamondCenter{
  transition: all 1s;
}
#DiamondCenter:hover{
  top: 5%;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div id="DiamondCenter"></div>
```

Comment: Harry thats a brilliant anwser !!! +1.Bro I have been in this site for some time and have never come a across a such a well formed answer for any of my questions

Comment: Harry Can we add box shadow to svg  ?

Comment: @SachinDivakar: Nope, can't add `box-shadow` but you can use `filter` (CSS or SVG). Do you have a sample image? I will try based on the image.

Comment: Would be very helpful if you can do that

Answer (score 5):

This is quite a complicated shape to complete in CSS, but as shown by others it is possible.

A good alternative though would be to use SVG. Its a vector graphic so it scales brilliantly for responsiveness and is very well supported ([CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg))

```html
<svg width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
  <path d="M5,1
           L9,5
           L5,9
           L1,5z" fill="grey" />
  <path d="M1,5
           L5,6
           L9,5
           L5,9z" stroke="orange" stroke-width=".1" stroke-dasharray="0,0,8.23,15" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create diamond shape using this css  ,                                      suppose this is div where you want above shape   id should be same as css (cut-diamond)

```
 #cut-diamond {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent red transparent;
    border-width: 0 25px 25px 25px;
    height: 0;
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px 0 50px 0;
}
#cut-diamond:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: -25px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red transparent transparent transparent;
    border-width: 70px 50px 0 50px;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vp9p12po/)

Comment: Bro Thats far from what I asked but plus +1 for the effort and this might be helpful for some one and one more thing if you answer a question please also add a demo using jsfiddle or codepen or jsbin